# Make Notifications As Read discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hey I need Example to make Notifications as read Its My Code For now

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')


token = "token"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged As " + client.user.name)
    message





client.run(token, bot=False)
```

I want it to login my account its already done, then Make All the Notifications 
 As Read.

I am New On discord.py so i hope for a little help
Thanks ZonEmOToRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can await [`Guild.ack`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.ack) to acknowledge every message in a certain guild.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged As " + client.user.name)
    message
    for guild in client.guilds:
        await guild.ack()
```

Comment: its say disocrd banned me

            <p>The owner of this website (discordapp.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
but i can access the website

Comment: Discord Say If you are being rate limited on an action it means that you have tried this action to many times in a short amount of time so you will need to wait for this rate limit timer to expire before you are allowed to try again. There is sadly no exact ETA for the timeout period.
How much delay i need to do

Comment: discord.py should do the rate limiting automatically.  It's more likely that you're being banned for using a user bot, which is against the discord TOS.  You can try adding a one second delay, that should be sufficent.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer I will do it tomorrow I need to change my ip

Comment: Hey Patrick I changed my ip and did 1 second delay and i still getting ban from discord

Comment: Because with the above code, you are sending read acknowledgements for every single message in every single server that you're in. Even if you wait a second, or even 10 minutes between acks, that is likely a massive amount of messages to mark as read in an instant. Depending on how many servers you're in of course. You should only ack() on specific messages or maybe specific guilds.